# White background with try again message on clicking edit

Tags: support, suggested-edits

When i clicked on the edit,I was directed to a white screen with following message on it

> There is a pending suggested edit in the queue, try again in a few minutes.

After few tries,the edit tag is not clickable indicating there is a suggested edit.

It should have pointed on the same page. what the reason behind redirecting to other page?

Answer (score 3):

When you reached the page with the "edit" link, the suggested edit wasn't submitted yet. By the time you clicked "edit", there was already a pending edit for this post, so system couldn't do anything except showing you the message.

When you returned on the previous page, you've got there after the edit was already submitted, it was the *same page*, but there was no edit link (because system realizes there's no point in it, though the check is only on the page load, it's not done dynamically). This is by design. The "white page" is in case you directly typed the link or the edit was submitted after you reach the post / tag wiki.